# Unexpected behaviour of NodeJS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently learning how to use NodeJS and wrote this relatively simple function to run at a fixed interval. The aim of this function is to retrieve newly created Droplets and update their IP addresses.

```
router.newDroplets = setInterval(function() {

    Server.find().then(function(svrs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < svrs.length; i++) {
            if (svrs[i].status == "Creating") {
                library.getDropletById(svrs[i].serverid).then(function(svr) {
                    if (svr.droplet) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < svr.droplet.networks.v4.length; j++) {
                            if(svr.droplet.networks.v4[j].type == 'public') {
                                var ip_address = svr.droplet.networks.v4[j].ip_address;
                                console.log(ip_address);

                                Server.update({serverid: svr.droplet.id}, {ipaddress: ip_address, status: "Online"}, function(error, n) {
                                    if (error) console.log(error);
                                    else console.log(n);
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (svr.id) {
                        // NOTE THIS LINE
                        console.log(svrs);
                    }

                }, function() {

                });
            }
        }
    }, function() {

    });

}, 2500);
```

The peculiar behaviour is with the line marked above.

When I use `console.log(svrs)`, I get an array of JSON documents in the Server collection in my MongoDB. However, when I use `console.log(svrs[i])`, `undefined` is logged in the console. This happens even if I declare `var i = 0;` outside the for loop. Why is this happening and how can I access `svrs[i]`?

Comment: `This happens even if I declare var i = 0; outside the for loop`, which `for` loop?

Comment: Use promises correctly and avoid writing such spaghetti code (nested promises).

Comment: Have you tried to log `i`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen I tried logging i and I receive 5, which is the number of documents in my Server collection.

Comment: @mparnisari I declared i outside the first for loop.

Comment: @Vohuman How do I use promises correctly without having spaghetti code? Are there any good tutorials for this? I'm currently searching for tutorials to learn more about this. Thank you.

Comment: I usually use bluebird library. It has pretty good documentations that can be relavent. Please check http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way promises work is that the promise chains run asynchronously. By the time that code runs, `i` is equal to `svrs.length`, so `svrs[i]` will be `undefined`. That's because the for loop executes in its entirety before any of the `then` callbacks are called. You could convert your code to use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

So you can try something like

```
svrs.forEach(function(svrInstance, i) {
  if (svrInstance.status == "Creating") {
    library.getDropletById(svrInstance.serverid).then(function(svr) {
      if (svr.droplet) {
        ...
      } else if (svr.id) {
        console.log(svrs[i]);
      }
     });
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and suggestion. I never knew that the `then` callbacks are called only after the `for` loop has finished looping.